# fullcalendar - change the place of 'prev,next today' button to custom selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, css-selectors, fullcalendar

I'm trying to change the place of the (`next,prev today`) buttons of `fullcalendar` to a specific `selector`. Is this possible or not?

I had tried to use javascript `append` to `selector` but the actions of buttons stopped working.

This is my `html` code:

```
<div id="header"></div>

    <div class="panel panel-default booking-panel">
        <div class="panel-heading " style="text-align: center;"> 
            <span class="left" style="float:left; text-transform: uppercase; font-weight: bold;">test </span> 
            <span id="title" style=" text-transform: uppercase; font-weight: bold;"> Employee </span> 
        </div>

        <div id="calendar"></div>

    </div>
```

I need the three buttons to be placed in `.left` selector as it's shown in this picture>>
[image]

> UPDATE

**test.php**

```
require_once 'calendar/config.php';
require_once 'calendar/functions.php';
$events = get_events();
$events = get_json($events);



if(!empty($_POST['clickDate'])){
print_r($_POST);
die;
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">    
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>First</title>

    <link href="datatable/css/vendor/font-awesome.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/style.css" type="text/css">

    <!--  Portrait phones and smaller -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (max-width: 480px)" href="style/1_portrait_phones_and_smaller-style.css" />

    <!--  Landscape phones and portrait tablets -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (max-width: 767px)" href="style/2_landscape_phones_and_portrait-style.css" />

    <!-- Portrait tablets and small desktops -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px)" href="style/3_portrait_tablets_and_small_desktops-style.css" />

    <!-- Landscape tablets and medium desktops -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1199px)" href="style/4_landscape_tablets_and_medium_desktops-style.css" />

    <!-- Large desktops and laptops --> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (min-width: 1200px)" href="style/5_large_desktops_and_laptops-style.css" />



    <!-- Calendar -->
    <link href="calendar/DateTimePicker/dist/DateTimePicker.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!--<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="calendar/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="calendar/css/jquery-ui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="calendar/fc/fullcalendar.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="calendar/fc/fullcalendar.print.css" media="print">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="calendar/css/style.css">
    <script src="calendar/js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <script>
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#header").load("include/header.php"); 

$("#next").click(function() {
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar("next");
});

$("#prev").click(function() {
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar("prev");
});

  $("#today").click(function() {
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar("today");
});
});
    </script>


    <div id="header"></div>


    <button type="button" id="prev">
&lt;
</button>
<button type="button" id="next">
&gt;
</button>
<button type="button" id="today">
Today
</button>
        <div id="calendar"></div>


<script>var events = <?php echo $events ?>;</script>
<script src="calendar/fc/lib/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="calendar/fc/fullcalendar.js"></script>
<!--<script src="fc/lang.ar.js"></script>-->
<script src="calendar/js/main.js"></script>
</body>
```

**main.js**

```
        $(document).ready(function() {    
        $("#calendar").fullCalendar({
        eventClick: function( event, jsEvent, view ) { 
            $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
        },

        dayClick: function(date, jsEvent, view) {
            //var clickDate = date.format();
            //$('#start').val(clickDate);
            //$('#dialog').dialog('open');
            // change the day's background color just for fun
            $(this).css('background-color', 'red');

            /*$.ajax({
                url: 'index.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {clickDate: clickDate},
                success: function(res){
                    console.log(res);
                },
                error: function(){
                    alert("ERROR!");
                }
            });*/

        },

        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay,listDay'
        },
        viewRender: function(view) {
            var title = view.title;
            $("#externalTitle").html(title);
        },
        slotDuration : '00:05:00',
        //editable: true, //Drag and Drop
        theme: true,
        eventSources: [
            {
                events : events,
                color : '#0EB6A2',
                textColor: '#fff'
            }
        ],

        //monthNames: ['كانون الثاني', 'شباط'],
        //monthNamesShort: ['ك ث', 'ش'],
        //dayNames: ['سبت', 'أحد'],
        //dayNamesShort: ['س', 'أ'],
        /*events: [
            {
                title: "Event 1",
                start: "2017-11-19"
            },
            {
                title: "Event 2",
                start: "2017-11-24"
            },
            {
                title: "Event 3",
                start: "2017-12-19"
            },
        ],*/

        /*eventSources: [
            'file.json'
        ]*/
    });

    $('#dialog').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        show: {
            effect: 'drop',
            duration: 500
        },
        hide: {
            effect: 'clip',
            duration: 500
        }
    });

    $('#open').click(function(){
        $('#dialog').dialog('open');
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't move the standard buttons to another place in the page, as far as I know.

But instead you could:

1) Hide the standard buttons by setting the "header" option such that they are not shown, e.g:

```
header: {
  left: '', //note no "buttons
  center: 'title',
  right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
},
```

See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/display/header/

2) Make your own buttons which just call fullCalendar's "next", "previous" and "today" methods when clicked, e.g.:

```
<button type="button" id="prev">
&lt;
</button>
<button type="button" id="next">
&gt;
</button>
<button type="button" id="today">
Today
</button>

$("#next").click(function() {
  $("#calendar").fullCalendar("next");
});

$("#prev").click(function() {
  $("#calendar").fullCalendar("prev");
});

$("#today").click(function() {
  $("#calendar").fullCalendar("today");
});
```

See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/current_date/next/ , https://fullcalendar.io/docs/current_date/prev/ and https://fullcalendar.io/docs/current_date/today/

You can place these buttons wherever you like in your page.

See http://jsfiddle.net/z8Lpvmyj/1/ for a working demonstration.

Comment: This could help me, but I don't know why it give me that $(...).fullCalendar is not a function When I click on ! 
Just se my updated Question code above.

Comment: probably it's trying to call fullCalendar code before the fullCalendar library is loaded. Move all the code which loads .js file to the top of the page inside the "head" tag (e.g. `<script src="calendar/fc/fullcalendar.js"></script>` and all those), and ensure the paths to the files are correct and the the webserver has correct permissions to serve them. Randomly you've used fullcalendar.js instead of .min.js when all your other files are .min.js (i.e. version for production use not testing). Also, you've included jQuery twice for no reason, so please remove one of the entries for that.

Comment: I had try to load `fullcalendar.js` in head before, but it doesn't work and give the same error, and also try including `.min.js` but the same error. PLUS I included jQuery just one time not twice,

Comment: The Problem was truely with loading jQuery twice. I have loaded first in `header.php` once and in `test.php` anothe time. You make me think about that Thanks alot. And Thank you for the Completly solving my problem. :)